# How to access the constant in the class?

Tags: php, class, oop, constants

Here is my code:

```
class ServerDirsController extends Controller {

    const DIR_PATH_LINUX   = '/opt/myprogram/';
    const DIR_PATH_WINDOWS = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\\parspack\\storage\\myprogram\\';

    protected function create_dir(Request $request){
        $path = constant("DIR_PATH_".strtoupper($this->os)) . $request->dir_name;
       ...
    }
```

It throws:

> ErrorException: constant(): Couldn't find constant DIR_PATH_WINDOWS in file ...

Any idea what's the correct syntax? Noted that  `self::constant("DIR_PATH_".strtoupper($this->os))` won't work.

---

To clarify the question, `constant("DIR_PATH_".strtoupper($this->os))` doesn't work and throws that error. The expected result is the value of one of those constants.

Comment: Use an associative array instead of dynamic variable names.

Comment: `constant('self::' . "DIR_PATH_" .strtoupper($this->os))`

Comment: Doesn't work. Throws `Error: Access to undeclared static property: App\Http\Controllers\ServerDirsController::$const in file`

Comment: What doesn't work? Just add `self::` right before `DIR_PATH_`. Or better yet, do this: `const DIR_PATH = ['LINUX' => '/opt/myprogram/', 'WINDOWS' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\\parspack\\storage\\myprogram\\'];`, so you can just index them (as Barmar suggested).

Comment: @MartinAJ It works here: https://ideone.com/ykHNFh